# How can webform load billing block information for a specified user?

Tags: webform-civicrm, stripe

The context is a staff member taking a phone call from a member and then filling in a webform including a payment for them.

The webform is added to the actions menu so the webform is passed '?cid=XXX' to load the contact.  The problem is that when it comes to payment (by Stripe), the billing block is loading the details of the person filling in the form, not those of the person on the phone.

How can webform be configured to use the details of the contact on the form?  Answers involving code writing are fine:-)

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is to try this PR by Coleman:
https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/pull/206

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @karing but I'm not following you.  The form is using 1 contact passed in as cid1 and the details of cid1 are populated as expected except for the billing block which is populated with the logged in user's details.  I want the billing block to also use cid1.

Comment: Sorry Aiden - I misread your question initially. Just pinged a collegue for some examples of their setup (was going to make you one but I’ve managed to botch my own test site for the moment); They have staff entering Donations and Calendar sales via Webform (by their office staff) - I think it closely resembles what you want to do;

Comment: Thanks - I've added some comments on that PR.